# I'm trying to remove a line of code that includes a certain character but I dont know how to go about it

Tags: java

I'm trying to remove a line of code that includes a certain character but I dont know how to go about it. This is my line of code and my output. I'm trying to remove the comments after the !# like (Example...Program) and #. And also white spaces. If you would like me to clarify, please let me know. Thank you! .

```
public class New {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = readFile("/Users/jalencarter/Desktop/snowflakeExample.txt");

        try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(str)) {

            scanner.useDelimiter("([*'])|\\s+");

            while(scanner.hasNext()){
                System.out.println(scanner.next());
            }

        }  
    }    

    static String readFile(String Name) {    

        File fi = new File(Name);     
        char[] buffer = null;    
        try {    
            BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader( new FileReader(fi));

            buffer = new char[(int)fi.length()];    
            int i = 0;    
            int j = buff.read();    
            while (j != -1) {    
                buffer[i++] = (char)j;    
               j = buff.read();   
            }    

        } catch (IOException e) {    
        }    

        return new String(buffer);
    }

}
```

Output

```
#!
Example
Snowflake
program
!#
parm
goat
cow;
star
=



;
while
goat
cow
{
#
repeat
unless
it
can
t
find
a
cow
goat
cow
=
star;
star
=
star



;
#
example
of
concatenation
}
return
goat;
```

Comment: What would the expected output be for the above file?

Comment: What do you mean by "removing line of code"? Source code is simple text and can be removed by pressing the delete keys in whatever editor you are using to code. Did you maybe mean that you want to remove characters/lines from the text file your programm is reading in?

Comment: Sorry, yes I meant remove character/lines from text file my program is reading in.

Comment: And the output should look something like                                             parm goat cow; star =; while goat cow { goat cow = star; star = star;} return goat; (vertically written)

Comment: And also, my professor was telling me to use tokens in order to get rid of the comments(the ones that are not in the new output)

Answer (score 0):

I see a pitfall here: A one-line comment ends at the next line break, but the scanner class does not distinguish between whitespaces and line breaks. I have no idea how to solve that with the scanner class, but I can provide you a working example without it:

Guessed input file (test.txt):

```
#!
    Example Snowflake
    program
!#

parm goat cow;
star = ;
while goat cow
{
    # repeat unless it can't find a cow
    goat cow = star;
    star = star;
    # example of concatenation
}
return goat;
```

Commented source code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        // Open the input file
        try (BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test.txt")))
        {
            boolean isBlockComment = false;
            String line;

            // Repeat reading until there no more line
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
            {
                // Does a block comment start in this line?
                int posi = line.indexOf("#!");
                if (posi >= 0)
                {
                    isBlockComment = true;

                    // If there are no characters before the comment, skip the whole line
                    if (posi == 0)
                    {
                        continue; // skip output
                    }

                    // keep only the left part before comment
                    line = line.substring(0, posi);
                }

                // Does a block comment end in this line?
                posi = line.indexOf("!#");
                if (posi >= 0)
                {
                    isBlockComment = false;

                    // If there are no characters after the comment, skip the whole line
                    if (posi + 2 == line.length())
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // keep only the right part after the comment
                    line = line.substring(posi + 2);
                }

                // Skip all lines within a block comment
                if (isBlockComment)
                {
                    continue;
                }

                // Does the line contain single-line comment?
                posi = line.indexOf("#");
                if (posi >= 0)
                {
                    // If there are no characters before the comment, skip the whole line
                    if (posi == 0)
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    // keep only the left part before comment
                    line = line.substring(0, posi);
                }

                // Until here, the comments are removed
                // test:
                // System.out.println(line);

                // The code below removes whitespaces

                // Remove whitespace at the beginning and end of the line
                line = line.trim();

                // Replace all multiple whitespaces by single whitespaces
                line = line.replaceAll("\\s{2,}", " ");

                // By using print instead of println, we remove line breaks
                System.out.print(line);

                // But we output a space after each line that is not empty
                if (!line.isEmpty())
                {
                    System.out.print(' ');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example output:

```
parm goat cow; star = ; while goat cow { goat cow = star; star = star; } return goat;
```

If you want to output each token separately (not line by line), then change the lower part to:

```
                // The code below removes whitespaces

                // Split the line at single or multiple whitespaces
                String tokens[] = line.split("\\s+");

                // Print only the tokens that are not empty
                for (int i=0; i<tokens.length; i++)
                {
                    if (! tokens[i].isBlank())
                    {
                        System.out.println(tokens[i]);
                    }
                }
```

Then the output would be:

```
parm
goat
cow;
star
=
;
while
goat
cow
{
goat
cow
=
star;
star
=
star;
}
return
goat;
```

Comment: If that if not 100% correct then please provide the input file, then we can check what is missing.

Comment: The input is correct but once I tried replacing that with my input rather that "test.txt", it's not printing anything

Comment: I am sure you can find out what's different in your text file. You may also use the debugger to execute the program line by line to see what's going on.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it!

Comment: Well this is how the input file looks :                                                                         #! Example Snowflake program !#
parm  goat  cow;
star = '*';
while goat cow {  # repeat unless it can't find a cow
 goat cow = star;
 star = star '*'; # example of concatenation
}
return goat;

Comment: Hey Stefan, I checked my text file, I used the debugger to delete some unnecessary breakpoints, executed the program line by line, and its still not printing anything.

Comment: Check the content of the variables while you step through it.

Comment: Every variable is running fine but i'm still not getting an output. Is it running for you correctly?

Comment: I copied the example output from my console. Anyway I executed both examples again today and still got the same proper output. I am using IntelliJ IDEA and openjdk version "11.0.6" 2020-01-14